# Error when installing Imagemagick 3.7.0 in XAMPP for Linux 8.2.4 (Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, pecl, lampp

I have installed the latest Xampp, and I 'm trying to install ImageMagick according to this https://gist.github.com/meleu/8ac2b8606964c6d1f2f508727e2e5f64

However, when I give this command to the terminal
`sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install imagick`

I am getting this result:

```
downloading imagick-3.7.0.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.7.0.tgz (360,138 bytes)
.........................................................................done: 360,138 bytes
33 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:561: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:561: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not exist
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not exist
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not look like a libtool script
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not look like a libtool script
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: using \`LTCC=$LTCC', extracted from \`$ofile'
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: using \`LTCC=$LTCC', extracted from \`$ofile'
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: tag name \"$tagname\" already exists
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:262: AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2821: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2820: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2821: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2820: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2821: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2820: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
Please provide the prefix of ImageMagick installation [autodetect] : 
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJrsGWw/imagick-3.7.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config --with-imagick
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /opt/lampp
checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I/opt/lampp/include/php/main -I/opt/lampp/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/lampp/include/php/Zend -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/lampp/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /usr/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /usr/sbin/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /opt/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /opt/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /opt/homebrew/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
found in /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 6.9.11
checking for MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header... /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h
checking PHP version is at least 5.3.2... yes. found 8.2.4
libs
-lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16


checking for MagickGetVersion... yes
checking omp_pause_resource_all usability... yes
checking Which flavour of OpenMP to link... checking for omp_pause_resource_all... no
checking for __omp_pause_resource_all... no
checking for omp_pause_resource_all in -lgomp... yes
GCC flavoured OpenMP
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJrsGWw/imagick-3.7.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJrsGWw/imagick-3.7.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJrsGWw/imagick-3.7.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I/opt/lampp/include/php/main -I/opt/lampp/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/lampp/include/php/Zend -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE   -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c -o imagick_file.lo  -MMD -MF imagick_file.dep -MT imagick_file.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJrsGWw/imagick-3.7.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJrsGWw/imagick-3.7.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I/opt/lampp/include/php/main -I/opt/lampp/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/lampp/include/php/Zend -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c -MMD -MF imagick_file.dep -MT imagick_file.lo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_file.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:21:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:42:10: fatal error: php.h: No such file or directory
   42 | #include "php.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:210: imagick_file.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I have also installed these:
`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`
and
`sudo apt install build-essential`

These posts didn´t help me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=install+imagemagick+lampp

These are some information which could help:

```
user@user-virtualbox:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

```
user@user-virtualbox:/opt/lampp$ sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl -V
PEAR Version: 1.10.13
PHP Version: 8.2.4
Zend Engine Version: 4.2.4
Running on: Linux user-virtualbox 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64
```

Comment: Have you installed `autoconf` package? Also `pkginfo` is likely to be useful.

Comment: Yes, I had installed the `autoconf` package. I am not sure about how the pkginfo would be useful for my case..

Comment: Sorry, I meant `pkgconfig` see https://askubuntu.com/a/1401159

Comment: No, this didn't help. I also noticed these lines in the begining of the result in my initial post: ```grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:```